# How to iterate DOM in JavaFX and find img and src tags?

Tags: java, dom, javafx

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package imagesget;

import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.concurrent.Worker;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;




/**
 *
 * @author biznis
 */
/**
 *
 * @author biznis
 */
public class ImagesGet extends Application {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {


        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        // create a HBox to hold 2 vboxes        
          HBox hbox = new HBox(10);
        // create a vbox with a textarea that grows vertically
       // HBox vbox = new VBox(10);
        //Label label1 = new Label("");
        final WebView browser = new WebView();
        final WebEngine wb = browser.getEngine();

    //grid.add(new Label("Input Url: "), 0, 0);
   // grid.add(notification, 1, 0);
        wb.load("http://epaper.timesgroup.com/Olive/ODN/TheEconomicTimes/#");
        wb.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(
            new ChangeListener<Worker.State>() {
                @Override
                public void changed(ObservableValue ov, Worker.State oldState, Worker.State newState) {
                    if (newState == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {
                        Document doc =   wb.getDocument();
                        try {
                            Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
                            transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "no");
                            transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
                            transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
                            transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
                            transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "4");
                            StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
                            try {
                                transformer.transform(new DOMSource(doc),
                                        new StreamResult(stringWriter));
                            } catch (TransformerException ex) {
                                Logger.getLogger(ImagesGet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                            }
                            String xml1 = stringWriter.getBuffer().toString();
                            System.out.println(xml1);

NodeList anchors = doc.getElementsByTagName("img");
System.out.println(anchors);

                        }catch (TransformerConfigurationException ex) {
                            Logger.getLogger(ImagesGet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                        } 
                    }
                }
            });
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```

this is what i tried but by this

```
NodeList anchors = doc.getElementsByTagName("img"); 
System.out.println(anchors);
```

im getting output is

> com.sun.webkit.dom.NodeListImpl@614d6ab6

how to get img tag
so can anyone tell me how to find img tag from outer html and download all images in local so tell me any documentation or any method so i can achieve this.

Comment: Perhaps start with the [documentation for NodeList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/NodeList.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are printing an object of type `org.w3c.dom.NodeList` to `System.out`. That is why `NodeList.toString()` is called and printed (which happens to be the the object's name).

I think you want to work with the nodes themselves. This code should give you the right idea how to deal with the nodes of your list:

```
NodeList anchors = doc.getElementsByTagName("img");
for (int index=0; index<anchors.getLength(); index++) {
    Node node = anchors.item(index);
    System.out.println(node.getNodeName());
    // ....
}
```

See [full Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html) to learn what you can do with `org.w3c.dom.Node`.

Comment: Right. These are all the image tags that you wanted to retrieve: _how to get img tag_

Comment: but im not getting img tag this are only img img i want complete img src

Comment: The code you provided in your question is not minimal (i.e. lots of dependencies). So, you cannot expect others to supply a code that works **just like that in your special context**. As I wrote in my answer, it should _ give you the right idea_ how to solve your special problem (preferably with full exception handling an logging in place). Again: Read Javadoc (just follow the link in the answer) and pay special attention on `Node.getAttributes()` and `NamedNodeMap.getNamedItem(String name)`.

Comment: well thanks but im nt able to understand which metrhod should used thats why i had put up the question.

Comment: NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("img");
        for (int i = 0; i < nList.getLength(); i++) {
            Node node = nList.item(i);
          //  if (node.getNodeType() == Element.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                Element eElement = (Element) node;
                System.out.println(eElement.getAttribute("src"));

Comment: i had able to do this but how can i download it in local.

Comment: This question is about finding tags in a DOM. Downloading is another topic. You should post a new question on that.